# Docker toolbox Mac OS Xdebug

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug, docker-machine

I'm using Docker Toolbox (docker-machine) in Mac OS 10.13, and trying to use Xdebug with PHP 7.1. At first I configured the interpreter via Docker container in virtual machine:

[image: Interpreter configuration]

Then I add the Server with mappings (8088 is exposed port of docker-machine):

[image: Docker Server]

And at last I create Debug Configuration:

[image: Debug Configuration]

Then I press "Start listening for Debug Connections" and trying to reload page in target project. And all I can see is infinite loader. If I switch off the listening page loads in 100 ms.

How I can use Xdebug with docker-machine?

Here is my Xdebug config from Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=true" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_mode=req" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_port=9000" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug_remote.log" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.idekey=PHP_STORM" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=1" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

Comment: > And all I can see is infinite loader. - Do you get anything in IDE? E.g. a breakpoint hit or a message like "Debug session finished without being paused..."?

Comment: 1) Look at the answer that George provided. 2) Ensure that PhpStorm can receive Xdebug connection on TCP 9000 port (make sure that it's PhpStorm that listens it, ensure that firewall is good here). Based on your description this should be OK already but worth double checking. 3) If still nothing, please collect Xdebug log for such unsuccessful debug session (you have it already, based on your `xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug_remote.log` line) and share it somewhere (do not copy-paste raw content here) -- it will tell where it tries to connect and what it tries to do.

Answer (score 2):

For "Docker for Mac" you need to use the special address to connect to the host from inside the container `xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal`.

> I WANT TO CONNECT FROM A CONTAINER TO A SERVICE ON THE HOST
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name host.docker.internal, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host. This is for development purpose and will not work in a production environment outside of Docker Desktop for Mac.

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/

Not sure it's exactly the same for Docker Toolbox (docker-machine) but worth a try.